# template class implementation errors

Tags: c++, templates

Below are my codes to generate random numbers based on user-defined weighting values. It all works, until I tried to make the type of data become any types, e.g. double, float. I have little experience implement them in practice, only read about them on textbooks. Can anyone helps me fix it?

Thanks,

```
class WeightedRandom
{
public:
    template <class T1,class T2>
    void setWeight(T1 i,T2 val)
    {
        m[i]=val;
        total+=val;
    }
    void generator()
    {
        int val=rand()%total;
        for (auto a:m)
        {
            if (val<a.second)
            {
                res[a.first]++;
                break;
            }
            val-=a.second;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (auto a:res)
        {
            cout<<a.first<<" "<<a.second<<endl;
        }
    }
private:
    template <class T1,class T2>
    unordered_map<T1,T2> m;
    template <class T3,class T4>
    unordered_map<T3,T4> res; // object-count
    int total=0;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    WeightedRandom WR;
    WR.setWeight(1, 5);
    WR.setWeight(2, 20);
    WR.setWeight(3, 50);
    WR.setWeight(4, 20);
    WR.setWeight(5, 10);
    int n=10000;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        WR.generator();
    }
    WR.print();
  }
```

Comment: what is the error? BTW, you have `int total` while you are having `total+=val;` where 'val' is of T2.

Comment: was the original where everything that's now a template was an int?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you simply need to template the class, allowing total to be the templated type.

```
#include<unordered_map>
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
template<typename T1,typename T2>
class WeightedRandom{
public:
    void setWeight(T1 i,T2 val)
    {
        m[i]=val;
        total+=val;
    }
    void generator()
    {
        T2 val= (T2) fmod(rand(),total);
        for (auto a:m)
        {
            if (val<a.second)
            {
                res[a.first]++;
                break;
            }
            val-=a.second;
        }
    }
    void print()
    {
        for (auto a:res)
        {
            cout<<a.first<<" "<<a.second<<endl;
        }
    }
private:
    unordered_map<T1,T2> m;
    unordered_map<T1,T2> res; // object-count
    T2 total=0;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    WeightedRandom<int,double> WR;
    WR.setWeight(1, 5.01);
    WR.setWeight(2, 19.99);
    WR.setWeight(3, 50.01);
    WR.setWeight(4, 19.99);
    WR.setWeight(5, 10.00);
    int n=10000;
    for (int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        WR.generator();
    }
    WR.print();
}
```

fmod takes a double, so if it's an int or a float, it will be promoted to a double and the result will be cast back down, or if it's a double, the cast does nothing. You might want to consider adding some checks to make sure you can *only* use double/float or char/short/int/long, because the user might use some class for the weights which wouldn't make too much sense:

```
...
class WeightedRandom{
    static_assert(!is_same<T,bool>(),"type can't be a bool");
    static_assert(is_arithmetic<T>(),"type needs to be an arithmetic");
...
```

Comment: Thank you, Austin. Really helpful.

Comment: no problem, although now that I think about it. You definitely need those checks, because fmod will fail for non arithmetics, so you would get a cryptic error message if you had WeightedRandom<int,ostream> or something

Comment: I tried to have a wrong input like:  WR.setWeight(true, 'a');    But the assert does not print out. It seems WeightedRandom<int,double> WR; has converted the bool type to int. So how should I make the assert works when there is a wrong input.

Comment: I just learned static_assert is something error check at compile time. This is why I did not make the assert work.

Comment: right, 'a' gets promoted into the double `97.0` because 97 is the ascii code for lowercase a, and bool gets promoted to the int `1`, because `true` is a set bit. these promotions happen as the values are passed into the function before it's evaluated. In my opinion, you shouldn't care if the user writes `WR.setWeight(1,97.0)` vs `WR.setWeight(true,'a')`. Both are equally valid, and enforcing the format of valid data is not the WeightedRandom class's responsibility

Comment: I agree. The enforcement should be placed at where receives user input.